# How can I set the base path for my RESTEasy resources in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I would like to set the base path under which all my RESTEasy resources would fall, without having to include a class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`.

Basically I would like to get rid of:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quarkus allows the base path to be configured in `application.properties` (see [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/0.11.0/extensions/resteasy/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/resteasy/deployment/ResteasyScanningProcessor.java#L205)).

So simply replace the class above with the following in `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.resteasy.path=/api
```

**UPDATE**

When using RESTEasy Reactive, as pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/a/72426133/2504224, one needs to use:

```
quarkus.resteasy-reactive.path=/api/
```

Answer (score 6):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55104603/476712) works for quarkus resteasy classic.

If you are using `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` you will need to set:

```
quarkus.resteasy-reactive.path=/api/
```

Comment: Good point, I'll also update the original answer!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Quarkus 2.13.1 and I made the following configuration. [More info](https://quarkus.io/blog/path-resolution-in-quarkus/).

Modify `application.properties` file and add the following lines

```
# Apply this path for the whole application, including metrics, etc.
quarkus.http.root-path=/api/
# In case you want to change a different route
quarkus.http.non-application-root-path=/q
```